# How to add new custom command to docker API?

Tags: docker, ubuntu-14.04

I'm trying to add a new customized command to the docker API, along with all the commands found at [docker/api/client](https://github.com/ThunderWiring/docker/tree/dry-run-test/api/client)

I added the following new `mycomand.go` file to the  forked repository:

```
package client    
import (
    "fmt"
    Cli "github.com/docker/docker/cli"
    flag "github.com/docker/docker/pkg/mflag"
)    
func (cli *DockerCli) CmdMycomnd(args ...string) error {
    cmd := Cli.Subcmd("CmdMycomnd", []string{"CONTAINER"}, Cli.DockerCommands["CmdMycomnd"].Description, true)
    cmd.Require(flag.Exact, 1)    
    cmd.ParseFlags(args, true)    
    fmt.Println("Hi!")      
    return nil
```

}

Also updated [docker/cli/common](https://github.com/ThunderWiring/docker/blob/master/cli/common.go) `DockerCommands` data structure to contain my new command.
Then pushed the commit to the branch in github, following the instructions on [docker doc page](http://docs.docker.com/opensource/project/set-up-git/).

Now, build the docker using `make` and tried to execute the binary of the 'new' docker which is found in `bundles/1.10.0-dev/binary/` by the command:

`./docker-1.10.0-dev mycomnd [option]`

**The Problem:** i get the error: `docker: 'mycomnd' is not a docker command.` Any idea how to get around this?

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to add a `.go` file in the directory `/api/client` along with all the API commands. 
   *The name of the file should be identical to the name of your command.*
2. In that `.go` file you should include whatever your command does in a function named `Cmd[YourCommandName]`
3. Commit and push the changes to your forked github branch.
4. Make the binary file

**Example:**

Say you want to add the command ‘talk’, so you do the following:

1. Add a new source file named `talk.go`: `$ touch talk.go`
2. Add contents of the `.go` source file.
3. Update the project on git hub:

   - `$ git add talk.go`      **NOTE:** your pwd should be `/api/client`
   - `$ git commit -s -m "Making a dry run test."`
   - `$ git push --set-upstream origin dry-run-test`
   - `$ <add your github account name + password>`
4. Now change directory to docker-master directory and `make` the project
5. Change directory to /bundles/1.10.0-dev/binary
6. Execute: ./docker-1-10-dev talk
7. DONE!

**Contents of our new `talk` command:**

```
package client

import (
    "fmt"
    Cli "github.com/docker/docker/cli"
    flag "github.com/docker/docker/pkg/mflag"
)

func (cli *DockerCli) CmdTalk (args ...string) error {
    cmd := Cli.Subcmd("talk", []string{"CONTAINER"}, Cli.DockerCommands["talk"].Description, true)
    cmd.Require(flag.Exact, 0)
    cmd.ParseFlags(args, true)
    fmt.Println("Hi")   
    return nil
}
```

**Screen Shot**
[image]